# MVVMLight ViewModelLocator to create new ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have been following the `mvvmlight` to code a project. I have 3 `xaml` files `MainWindow`, `View1`, `View2`,

I have registered all three viewmodels in my `ViewModelLocator`, as well as a data service used by `View1Model`

```
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IView1Service, View1Service>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<View1Model>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<View2Model>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }
    public View1Model View1
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<View1Model >(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }
    public View1Model View2
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<View2Model >(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }
```

The `View1Model` requires a `IView1Service` as constructor input,

```
   public View1Model(IView1Service view1Service)
    {
        _view1_service = view1Service;
    }
```

In my `App.xaml` I have registered them as below

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:View1Model}">
          <views:view1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:View2Model}">
          <views:View2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And of course `View1` `View2` are `xmal` files under the `MyProject.View` namespace.

I was trying to initialize all the views in my `MainViewModel`, so I access all the viewmodel instances in `MainViewModel`

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Add available pages
        PageViewModels.Add(new View1Model(new View1Service()));  // <========How to get this from the ViewModelLocator ?
        PageViewModels.Add(new View1Model());

        // Set starting page
        CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

    }
```

`PageViewModels.Add(new View1Model());` in this line of code, I was hoping to get it from `ViewModelLocator` instead of passing a `View1Service` object. But the `Locator` I registered in `App.xaml` is not accessible here, what is the best to way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by creating the ViewModelLocator as a private field in my ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ViewModelLocator _locator;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _locator = new ViewModelLocator();
    }
}
```

Then you can access your ViewModels through your ViewModelLocator using: `_locator.View1`, `_locator.View2`, etc.

Comment: it seems to be working, however, I do have one follow-up question, what is the relationship of the `Locator` i have declared in `App.xaml` to this private member `_locator`.  In `MainWindow.xaml`, I have declared `DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`, so what is the `DataContext` for `MainWindow.xaml` in this case?

Comment: They're the same thing. The ViewModelLocator is a singleton - under 'normal' conditions there is only ever 1 ViewModelLocator, which returns the same instances of your ViewModels.

Answer (score 3):

I've using MVVMLight to developed for the Universal App, not WPF. But I guess it should be similar.

You don't have to explicitly create a new instance of the ViewModel. It is a Singleton, so a instance will be created when `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>()` is first called.

Also, SimpleIoc is smart enough to find a suitable class (match the type that register before, `IView1Service` in this case) to instantiated if it needs a parameter.

The `Locator` you registered in App.xaml is used in other xaml, like:

```
<Page
...
DataContext="{Binding View1, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
>
```

To get the ViewModel instance in code, just like @goobering 's answer.

```
View1Model vm = (new ViewModelLocator()).View1;
```

It is safe to create many ViewModelLocator instances, and the ViewModel returned is the same object.